# mysql stored routine vs. mysql-alternative?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, cassandra, bigtable

We are using a mysql database w/ about 150,000 records (names) total. Our searches on the 'names' field is done through an autocomplete function in php. We have the table indexed but still feel that the searching is a bit sluggish (a few full seconds vs. something like Google Finance w/ near-instant response). We came up w/ 2 possibilities, but wanted to get more insight:

1. Can we create a bunch (many thousands or more) of stored procedures to speed up searches, or will creating that many stored procedures bog-down the db?
2. Is there a faster alternative to mysql for "select" statements (speed on inserting & updating rows isn't too important so we can sacrifice that, if necessary). I've vaguely heard of BigTable & others that don't support JOIN statements....we need JOIN statements for some of our other queries we do.

thx

Comment: Stop. Have you tried http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html ? Usually produces fantastic results, especially on the first use.

Comment: I will read up on caching. Is there a good paper out there ( or video) that compares the strengths/weaknesses of each of the major databases (ie mysql vs. oracle vs. cassandra, etc)? Before I delve much more into mysql I want to make sure that I have the right d-base

Comment: Wait, a `select name from names where name like 'foo%' limit 10` is taking seconds?! It shouldn't. That is a simple index operation. Are you *sure* you have indices? Please give an example query, along with `explain` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Forget about stored procedures. They wont do any good for you.
2. Mysql is good choice, it's often considered as fastest RDBMS. And there is no need to look for 'faster alternative to select statement'.

Abnormal query execution time you mentioned is a result of server misconfiguration or wrong database schema, or both. Please read [this response on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/199003/recommend-a-good-guide-for-mysql-optimization/199017#199017) or update your question here: provide server configuration, part of database schema and problem query along with `explain select ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache the information in memory to avoid making repeated calls to the database.

Comment: would having thousands & thousands of select statements in the cache slow us down, though? The closes example I have is Google Finance's autosearch function....would storing all the calls to tickers (& partial tickers) in cache practical or are they likely doing something else?

Comment: also, what happens when the underlying data changes in the table...does the cache continue to return the old data?

Comment: a couple of hundred thousand records isn't a problem for a cache.

Comment: no, I mean a couple hundred thousand cached queries. I have millions of records

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to expire the cache if you change the data, but as you said, that's not common, so you can even do that on a semi-automated basis and not worry about it if necessary. You should check out [this MySQL.com article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html), as well as perhaps explore the MEMORY storage engine (sorry, new and can't post more than one hyperlink per post?!) which takes a little bit of coding around to use but can be extremely efficient.

What's the actual query time (vs page time)? On a reasonably modern server that's not loaded to hell, MySQL should be able to do an autocomplete query on 150k rows much, much, faster than two seconds. Missing some indexes?